# Windows batch: For loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a file FileLis.txt which contains the data as

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt and so on.
```

Below part of the code `%%a` displays the results exactly as my file list as above but when I assign the same to a variable it gets only first line (`set "TARG_FILE=%%a"`).
Can anyone explain why is this difference in behavior and what is the correct way of writing it?

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Write list of files of the input folder to a file 
DIR /o-d /b c:\data\All_Inputfiles\*.* > D:\data\FileLis.txt

Set AllInputFile= D:\data\FileLis.txt

ECHO  " %AllInputFile%>>D:\data\debuginfo.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%AllInputFile%) do (  
 ECHO  "Start of Main Loop Iteration#######################">>D:\data\debuginfo.txt  
 ECHO 
 set "TARG_FILE=%%a"
  ECHO "TARG_FILE " %TARG_FILE% "line="%%a>>D:\data\debuginfo.txt
 ECHO 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ECHO "TARG_FILE " !TARG_FILE! "line="%%a>>D:\data\debuginfo.txt
```

Use it like that.For more info -> http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html